# If $f$ is continuous, then there exists $x+\frac{1}{n}\in[0,1]$ and $f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(x)$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, such that $f(0)=f(1)$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that $\exists x\in [0,1]$ such that $x+\dfrac{1}{n}\in[0,1]$ and $f\left(x+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=f(x)$.

My approach: The interval $[0,1]$ is connected, then if $f$ is continuous, we have $f([0,1])\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a interval. And I suppose that, I can define a closed path such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Any hint pls,

Comment: Do you know a proof in the case $n=2$? It seems you've got the right tool (i.e. the intermediate value theorem), but maybe need to think of how to use it. Consider that $f(x)=f(x+\frac{1}2)$ is the same as $f(x+\frac{1}2)-f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to $g(x) = f(x + 1/n) - f(x)$ on $[0, 1-1/n]$.

Comment: If $g(x)=f\left(x+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)$, then if I sum $g\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)$=$f\left(\dfrac{i+1}{n}\right)$ $-f\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)$ from $i=1$ to $n-1$, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{g\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)}=f(1)-f(0)=0$, this mean in the sum exists terms $>0$ and $<0$, by Intermediate Value theorem, exists $x$ such that $g(x)=0\implies f\left(x+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)=0$. This is correct?

Comment: Not quite: all the terms in the sum could be $0$, but that's also good.

Comment: And then what is the best way to answer this?, And how I assure the existence of such $x+\dfrac{1}{n}\in [0,1]$?? Regards