# Proving that there exists a solution to $f\bigl(x+\frac1n\bigr)-f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

> Given $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ which is continuous, $f(0)=f(1)$, and $n\in\mathbb N^*$ (doesn't include $0$), show that $f\bigl(x+\frac1n\bigr)-f(x)=0$ has a solution.

This was shown to me by an acquaintance who told me that if we consider $h(x)=f\bigl(x+\frac1n\bigr)-f(x)$, then the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\bigl(\frac kn+\frac1n\bigr)-f(\frac kn)=0$ somehow tells us that there are two opposite terms in that sum, and, as such, we can apply the IVT to $h(x)$.

Clearly the sum is null because it is in the form $f(1) + (f(a)-f(a)\text{ same argument a})+(f(b)-f(b)\text{ same argument b})+...-f(0)$ and $f(1)=f(0)$, not because there somehow exists two different in argument terms that cancel $f(a)+f(b)=0$.
In any case, we require a $h(a)$ and a $h(b)$ such that $h(a)h(b)<0$, not in terms of $f$.

But, from what I have understood, this is the correction given by their professor, so maybe I am missing something?

EDIT: Ignore the following nonsense...
<strike>I thought of going about it by contradiction, but the use of a limit leaves me undecided as to whether this counts as a solution.</strike>

The negative of the proposition is $\exists n\in\mathbb N^*\,|\,\forall x\in\mathbb R,\,f\bigl(x+\frac1n\bigr)-f(x)\neq0$, i.e $f\bigl(x+\frac1n\bigr)<f(x)$ or $>$. In both cases, if we take $n\to\infty$, we get $f(x)<f(x)$, which is impossible.

Any comments? Thank you!

Comment: a) How do you think you get an impossible inequality in the limit? -- b) also, it is principally possible that for some $n$ we have $>$ and for others we have $<$

Comment: yes... for some reason, i still was thinking that i had a $\forall n$... thanks. @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1433031/42969.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(f\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right) = f(1) - f(0) = 0$$ (it's a telescoping sum).  If any $f\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = 0$ you're done.  They can't all be positive or the sum would be positive, and similarly they can't all be negative.  So if none are $0$, there are
two consecutive ones that have opposite sign, say $f((k+1)/n) - f(k/n) < 0$ and $f((k+2)/n) - f((k+1)/n) > 0$.  Now apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to $h(x) = f(x+1/n) - f(x)$ on $[k/n, (k+1)/n]$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is constant, then we are done.  So assume $f$ is nonconstant and, without loss of generality, assume
$$
f(0) = f(1) = 0.
$$
This, together with the nonconstancy of $f$, implies that $f$ either attains a strictly positive maximum at a point interior to $[0, 1]$ or attains a strictly negative minimum at a point interior to $[0, 1]$.  For definiteness, assume $f$ attains a strictly positive maximum at a point $\overline{x}$ interior to $[0, 1]$.

Introduce the function
$$
g(c) = (\max f) - c, \quad c \geq 0.
$$
Then
$$
g(\overline{x}) = 0.
$$
For $c$ close enough to $\max f$, but strictly smaller, the equation
$$
g(c) = 0
$$
had at least two solutions (we prove this by applying the Intermediate Value Theorem twice, once on $[0, \overline{x}]$ and once on $[\overline{x}, 1]$).  Among these solutions, let $x_{c,-} < \overline{x} < x_{c,+}$ be the closest two to $\overline{x}$.  Let $h(c)$ be the distance between these two.  It has a removable discontinuity at $c = \overline{x}$, which we fill by putting
$$
h(\overline{x}) = 0,
$$
extending $h$ to being a continuous function for $c \in [0, \mbox{some positive }\epsilon]$.

Picking a positive integer $n$ large enough to have
$$
{1 \over n} < \epsilon,
$$
we see that there exists a $c$ such that
$$
h(c) =  {1 \over n }.
$$

P.S. Realizing I may have misread the quantifier for $n$, hence the Community wiki.